# How to rewrite www URL to non-www URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, kohana

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file, I want to know how can I rewrite my URLs from www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com, I'm using Kohana 3.2 and haven't found info about it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

I have tried the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

But it results into "too many redirects"

Comment: check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1270281/1409771

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: You're looking for something like this: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.` 
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```