# WWW to NON WWW Urls (Remove WWW) using Apache (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, no-www

I have to redirect my website from `https://www.example.com/` to `https://website.com/`.

**SSL** is properly installed on my server.

I am using **Apache** and have to do this using **Apache** (either `httpd.conf/ssl.conf` or `.htaccess`)

I have used almost all of the methods I could search for but none of them work for me.

- `http://www.example.com/` redirects properly to `https://example.com/`
- `http://example.com/` redirects properly to `https://example.com/`.

But

- `https://www.example.com/` **does not redirect** properly to `https://example.com/`.

It gives me "invalid certificate error" and when I add an exception (accept the certificate) in the browser then it redirects to `https://example.com/`. But I don't want to add this exception (adding the certificate in the browser).

Please note that my SSL certificate is issued for `example.com` and not `www.example.com`.

Following are my `.htaccess` rules and conditions

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

I have used the following too but these didn't work either:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Used this as well but no luck

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

No luck with this too

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have tried 5-6 other solutions (similar to above) but none worked. All work for the first two patterns I mentioned above but none work for `https://www`.

Note that these conditions of `.htaccess` are reached, I mean `.htaccess` is not being ignored. I have verified this using redirects and also the two patterns mentioned above are working as well.

In `httpd.conf/ssl.conf` the `AllowOverride` directive is set to `All`.

I have access to `httpd.conf/ssl.conf`.

**PHP Version** 5.5.29

**Apache** 2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.5.29

**Hostname:Port**   example.com:443

Last but not least my website `https://example.com/` does not open in Internet Explorer and Safari and give certificate issues (errors) but when I check my domain using SSL checkers (multiple) then all SSL checkers mentions that SSL is properly installed.

Check this image, this will explain things better:

[image: Browsers reporting SSL cert error]

Complete `.htaccess` is given below:

---

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
DirectoryIndex index.html Home.php index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(blogs)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?mod=resturants&name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^$ Home.php [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `https://{REQUEST_URI}` <- aren't you missing something?

Comment: @hjpotter92 what thing? Please mention in detail, I am not good enough with this stuff.

Comment: Check the image, if this may help you http://i.imgur.com/lOy65rs.jpg

Comment: It should be `https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`

Comment: No luck :( Same issue. If you have time please read my conversation with Rizwan Ranjha below and check this image. Website do not work in IE and Safari,  i.imgur.com/lOy65rs.jpg

Comment: I also have posted complete .htaccess in post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please note that my SSL certificate is issued for website.com and not
>   www.website.com.

*That is your main problem*. You are *never* going to be able to redirect from `www` to `non www` without a **valid** certificate for `www`. The reason is the connection is handled first before the web server processes anything else including any rewrite rules. So when your browser connects to your site using the https protocol, it has to check for a valid certificate because that's the very nature of SSL to make sure the connection is secure. Then once that is done, Apache will process web server rules that you have in place like rewrites. So it can't rewrite from www to non www until the connection is completed correctly. In order for that to happen you also need a certificate for `www` as well. The rewrite rules are not the problem.

This topic comes up quite frequently and there is no way around it. That's the nature of SSL/encryption and how it works.

When buying a cert, try not buying just the domain name, because *some* CA's will only give you that without www. But if you use `www.example.com` in your CSR you will get both `www.example.com` and `example.com` in the same certificate 99% of the time. Then you won't have to worry about this issue. They are stupid cheap so it shouldn't be an issue to get another one. SSls.com has them for 4.99/yr.

Comment: I have asked for www.website.com certificate but why **http : // www.website.com/** and **http : // website.com/** are successfully redirecting to **https : // website.com**?

Answer (score -1):

Did you Try this ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: Same issue (error) which I explained in post. **This Connection is Untrusted** with https :// www,domain.com/ whereas it should had been redirected to https://domain.com/

Comment: does your SSL certificate cover both www and non www as it seems than its issue of SSL not redirecting.

Comment: NO, SSL covers only domain.com and not the www.domain.com, this is the reason I am trying to redirect everything to domain.com

Comment: Hi, I have update the answer, please check again and paste this in start of the .htaccess

Comment: No luck :( Same issue. If there is anything that can I do in httpd.conf or ssl.conf?

Comment: if you do manually https://domain.com , does it working fine? If Yes , then only issue is with redirect.

Comment: IE and Safari are not opening domain.com at all, Firefox and Chrome opens the website (https) but may be do not accept the certificate fully. Check this photo this will explain things better to you. http://i.imgur.com/lOy65rs.jpg

Comment: better to post your .htaccess (complete)

Comment: I have updated the post and have added the complete .htaccess