# htaccess rewrite for https multiple domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, ssl-certificate

I'm just going crazy with my issue and hope for your help.

I have one webstore with two domains linking to one same path. And webstore is choosing itself which content should be shown depends on domain.

- www.yogabox.de - German content
- www.yogabox.co.uk - English content

I'm trying to rewrite all kinds of yogabox.de to https://www.yogabox.de und the same for yogabox.co.uk to https://www.yogabox.co.uk

Here is the result:

[image]

I'm using those rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www\.yogabox\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^yogabox\.co\.uk$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www\.yogabox\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      https://www.yogabox.de/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^yogabox\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www\.yogabox\.de$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^yogabox\.de$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      https://www.yogabox.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Only https://yogabox.de and https://yogabox.co.uk are wrong. Where is the problem?

I have already checked the problem with not valid certificate like here [WWW to NON WWW Urls (Remove WWW) using Apache (.htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039666/www-to-non-www-urls-remove-www-using-apache-htaccess/33045563#33045563)

But the certificates are valid for www and without www.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` applies to http. What do you want for  `https://yogabox.de` and `https://yogabox.co.uk`? `https://www.` ? There is no rule for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rules don't match the `ssl non-www` urls, so the redirection from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` isn't happening on your server.  .

You can use the following generic  rule to redirect your domains to `https://www` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing these rules.

Comment: mate! it it a beautiful and best rule ever! thank you a lot. All domains are redirected properly. awesome! resolved!