# Non-www htaccess redirect only works on the home page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I'm having trouble redirecting the www requests to non-www on my Wordpress-based site. The code I used works fine on the homepage, but not on any sub pages.

I'm using the following code taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www) question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be fine. is this rule above your wordpress rules? Also clear your cache or try in a new browser.

Comment: @PanamaJack Turns out my rule was under the WP rule. Never would have thought of that, thank you! :)