# http to https redirect along with www to non-www in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my site from http to https and from www to non-www at the same time. This code from Andron [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www) works but with a few glitches. I've slightly tweaked it and redirected everything from the non-https to https as well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For the following situations the redirect works flawlessly and redirects to the `non-www https` version:

```
domain.com
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/page
```

However, when I enter the `domain.com/page` or `http://domain.com/page` I see only the `non-secure http non-www` version.

How do I make sure that all URLs redirect to the `secure https non-www` version of the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rule that does both `http->https` and `www` removal in single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Multiple redirects should better be avoided for SEO purpose.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! :)

Comment: @anubhava Do you have a similar solution but with `Redirect`?? I tried but I'm not able to redirect both www and non-www at the same time

Comment: Don't use `Redirect` otherwise you will get redirect loop. Better use `mod_rewrite` as suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```