# redirect 301 subdomain to https://subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to do two 301 redirects in my .htaccess:
1. 
members.mydomain.com/* to https://members.mydomain.com/*

2.
members.mydomain.com/topic/yada?subject=1 to https://members.mydomain.com/topic

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code in your Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


#Redirect "member.mydomain.com" to https

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^members.mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
#Remove /yada?subject=1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /topic/yada/\?subject=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /topic/? [NC,L,R]
```

I used R "Temp redirect" for testing purpose and to avoid browser cache.
Change R to R=301 when you are sure the code is working fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I added the code to .htaccess after # END WordPress but with no change. :(