# .htaccess - redirect all to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect all pages to non-www https?

```
http://example.com/* -> https://example.com/*
http://www.example.com/* -> https://example.com/*

https://www.example.com/* -> https://example.com/*
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this problem is solved. Look here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Comment: Actually, this question has been answered about 65936502659 times alone here on SO.

Comment: @HubertS, yes but if I type just example.com, it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```