# rewrite rule for non.www to https to www.https on .htacces magento

Tags: mysql, linux, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I want to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com for my website. Can you help me with the code to put it on .htaccess file. the site is in magento.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Explained: If the requested host does not start with www., redirect it to start with www

Comment: Thankyou , BUT I need the code for HTTPS.. without www redirect to with www

Answer (score 0):

Source|Reference: http://codingbasics.net/magento-htaccess-file-optimized-speed-security-seo/

The link above has a default Magento htaccess file that has been optimized for speed and SEO and has code for rewriting non-www to www, but does not have the code for rewriting HTTPS/SSL non-www to www. So I have grabbed the htaccess code section from the link/site above and made the additional edits to the code below for rewriting HTTPS/SSL non-www to www.

```
##### Search Engine redirects and rewrites for SEO purposes #####

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Rewrite|Redirect http to https|SSL & non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    ##### Redirect away from /index.php and /home   
    ##### Warning: This index.php rewrite will prevent Magento 
    ##### Connect from working. Simply comment out the  
    ##### following two lines of code when using Connect.
    ##### Please note - https://www. if not using www simply use https://

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ##### Please note - https://www. if not using www simply use https://
    redirect 301 /home https://www.yourdomain.com

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```