# Own example.org and can't get www.example.org to redirect

Tags: apache, no-www

I own `http://0x3c.org/` and everything is working as it should. I am using Google Domains and have Dynamic DNS set up with them to point to the Apache server inside of my house.

My issue is that `http://www.0x3c.org/` does not redirect to `http://0x3c.org/`, instead it says that `http://www.0x3c.org/` does not exist. Additionally, I do not want `http://www.0x3c.org/` to exist.

I would like for it to redirect, and don't know how to go about setting it up. Can anyone guide me as to how to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www.0x3c.org has to exist, in order to redirect the requests. You have to create a DNS (CNAME) entry for www.0x3c.org, direct it (preferably) to the same server that serves 0x3c.org and then use Apache rewrite rules, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: So, I added the rewrite conditions and rule to my .htaccess file in my root folder and restarted my apache service. I then went to my Google domain settings and added a CNAME entry at the bottom of my DNS settings page structured like so : `Name: www` `Type: CNAME` `TTL: 1h` `Data: 0x3c.org` and it doesn't appear to be redirecting as it should.

Comment: Strange that it's not working on my admin computer. Ah, well. It did work on my phone, you're right! So thank you!