# Redirect www and index.html to root non-www .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I  want to make a rule in my .htaccess file, to redirect my www.example.com and 
www.example.com/index.html to example.com

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine both requirement in a single rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html[?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:index\.html)?$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file. And add this:

```
#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.YOURDOMAIN\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://YOURDOMAIN.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks it works fine for non-www but it is still missing the redirect from www.example.com/index.html to example.com

Answer (score 0):

thiis should work seamlessly

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitename\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sitename.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```