# session missing when add url with www redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have redirect the url

http://hostname.com

session wiorking fine

When add a **www** in url session removed in sesrver.

http://www.hostname.com

Wht this problem occured a. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

www is a totally different website with non-www. I suggest you to redirect to non-www to www using htaccess

this is www to non-www [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)
[Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)