# www to non www redirection through .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect

This is the code in my.htaccess file

```
#force non-www

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([a-z0-9_]+\.)?example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This code redirects www.example.com to example.com

But whenever there is something ahead of the url

Example -

> `www.example.com/file-consumer-something`

It redirects me to `example.com`

I want it to become `example.com/file-consumer-something`

Can someone help ?

Comment: This code should already be doing what you require (that's what the `%{REQUEST_URI}` bit does)? If this is a recent change then make sure you've cleared your browser cache. However, your code does more than simply redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com` - do you have multiple domains? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: I am using shared hosting Cpanel
have a look at my .htaccess file.
Sorry It exceeds the limit here.

http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=58892297715516577289&t=5889229771551657728991750

Comment: "exceeds the limit"?! How big is this file? That download link gets blocked as malicious by my browser.

Comment: It exceeded the word limit 

see the .htaccess content from here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8cNo7CwEBq9clJyVi1kWU54Sk0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted already looks like it should work as required. However, it's possibly conflicting with existing (mod_alias / mod_rewrite) directives in your `.htaccess` file. It's also doing more than you seem to require, so can be simplified.

Try the following instead. This should go near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```