# Index.php page not working after adding this in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

After making this .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 localhost/website/error404.html 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)/?$ users.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

If I open a folder inside a website like: `localhost/website/user` 
Then it redirects me to error404 page. I need to type `localhost/website/user/index.php` in order to open it. How to fix it guys?

Comment: did you write RewriteBase ?

Comment: I just added the .htaccess file, that's all.

Comment: If i remove line 2 and 3, it is working.

Comment: index.php coming in all URL

Comment: But I used to get redirected to users/index.php, if i just type /users, but now, i need to type whole users/index.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www