# redirect from www. to root domain ( without www.)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, .htaccess

How do you force the root domain uses? I want to know how to do this in

```
html, php, Javascript, .htaccess,jQuery,  ajax.
```

I know about the meta refresh

## as shown here:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

## and here I know this too:

```
<body onload="window.location.href = 'your URL';"></body>
```

## as well as: Php

```
<?php header('Location: https://example.com'); ?>
```

**but none of those work for what I want.**
Multiple methods would be nice!

Comment: did you try searching? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270281/6468413

Comment: this goes in your server config, see the docs for the one you're using

Comment: @JapanGuy that didn't work

Comment: what went wrong with the above?

Comment: easy way is using htaccess

Comment: @javamaster any reason why it didnt work? add these to your .htaccess 
`RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrite.log"`
`RewriteLogLevel 9`
to check if htaccess rewrites are working

Comment: @JapanGuy thank you I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your htaccess rewrites are working.

use this on your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```