# Redirect all subdomains and www to non-www

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect all subdomains and www to my main “non-www” domain.

So:

www.example.com
AND 
sub.example.com
AND 
www.sub.example.com

Should all become:

example.com

How could I do this using `mod_rewrite`?

Thanks

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Comment: I dont see how would this redirect subdomains as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: As already mentioned, I need to redirect every subdomain as well.

Comment: @BalázsVincze have you tried the question answer?

Comment: Yes, that only works for www redirect, not subdomains

Comment: at the bottom of the page there is an answer by @Gregor Macgregor  which works with subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234723/589924) suggests the following redirects `www.example.com` to `example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As such, you could use the following to redirects anything that ends with `.example.com` to `example.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The following is a more generic solution (but it doesn't work for domains that are part of multi-level TLDs, such as `www.theregister.co.uk`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just what I needed! 

Could you maybe tell me, how to redirect http request to https for the main domain?