# Django: HTTP 301 redirect

Tags: django, dns

Whenever someone visits `www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com` I want to forward visitors to `https://example.com`

I first thought I can do this in my DNS Records, but DNSimple support said it has to be via 301 redirects. Anyone can help me how to solve this in Django?

Comment: This is something you would do in your web server, not in Django.

Comment: Hmm okay then I'm confused dnsimple.com (where I am hosting my domain) don't seem to have this kind of 301 redirect.

Comment: If you're using Apache, this can be done using .htaccess configuration as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www  You will probably need to have admin access to the server. You may need to enable rewrites in your apache server first (`AllowOverride all` in your virtual host)