# http://www. to http:// redirect not working at all

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want a rather simple feature, I want my website to work when someone puts a www. before my domain name. My preference is to redirect all `http://www.` requests to `http://` without anything complicated.

I have tried two methods to this and neither works desirably. The first option was to simply add this following rewrite engine command in the site's `.htaccess` (which, for the record, I confirmed was working)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried numerous variations of this code, and none of them do a thing. Even after resetting my browser cache, accessing through Tor, if I enter my website with the `www.` prefix then it simply doesn't load and Firefox gives me a "server not found" error.

The second thing that I have tried is to remove all rewrite codes and simply add the DNS record A, with the host `www` that points to my IP address. After waiting a little bit, the website was now working! However, it was incredibly inconsistent, because if I were to access `www.example.com` then it would remove the `www.`, but if I went to `www.example.com/page.html` then it wouldn't remove it (but it'd still work). Another weird issue is that if I typed `www.example.com/folder/page`, it'd send me to `www.example.comfolder/page`.

Does anyone have any advice on what should I do or what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: For simpler redirection need, have a look at `mod_alias` and its `Rewrite` directives, this is far simpler than `mod_rewrite` and if possible you should try to use the main Apache configuration files instead of `.htaccess`, especially for redirection needs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Tried this but doesn't do anything either. Am I missing something completely? Because of the 10 or so different RewriteEngine codes I tried none of them do anything.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not necessarily an answer, but my reputation is not yet sufficient to post a comment.)

The previous comment looks like it should do the job, so something unexpected is going on with the rewrite.

You might try enabling rewrite logging at a low level to see what is going on with the rewrite rule.  Increase logging level by one level if the issue is not revealed.  Note that logging mod_rewrite actions can produce really big logs, so it is prudent to try this on a testbed or a relatively idle host.

```
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteLogLevel: Controls verbosity of mod_rewrite log
#                  0=off, 9=max
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

As a side note and imo, I would do this in the config file and not in an .htaccess file because this rule should be applied site-wide on this host/vhost.  This also makes it impossible for Apache to avoid executing the rewrite by ignoring the .htaccess file.