# Website uses URLs with www and non-www subdomain which may cause duplicate content and bad links

Tags: html, .htaccess, server

How can I redirect `www` to non `www` for sub-directories? It is OK for home page but for sub-directories, it doesn't work. My sub-directory files have dynamic content.

My `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule blog/(.*)/ viewpost.php?page=$1
RewriteRule blog/(.*) catpost.php?page=$1
```

but it only affects the home page, not sub-directories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: Now what, subdirectories or subdomain?