# Gatsby how to redirect all www. to non www

Tags: javascript, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

What is a way to redirect all requests from www.any-page to the non www. version? I've looked into createRedirect but that only allows the absolute path to be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've looked into `createRedirect` but that only allows the absolute path
> to be specified?

This is no true. In the [examples](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500003051241-Working-with-Redirects-and-Rewrites) you can see relatives redirections:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createRedirect } = actions;

    createRedirect({
    fromPath: `/blog/recipes/*`,
    toPath: `/recipes/*`,
  });
}
```

Regarding your question: the kind of redirections you are trying to apply should be done in the server, not in the client, depending on your infrastructure you can use a simple `.htaccess` file to AWS Lambdas. For example, the following `.htaccess` will do the redirection you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*Extracted from [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)*

Place a file named `.htaccess` in the `/static` folder and Gatsby will do the rest.

You can also use [`gatsby-plugin-htaccess`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-htaccess/) for a more succinct approach.