# how to redirect www to main domain using laravel htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have separate subdomain in laravel.
I want when some one visit: *[www.shawn.com](http://www.shawn.com)* it will automatically redirected to *shawn.com* but if anyone visit *hello.shawn.com* its ok to visit.

but if another one visit *[www.hello.shawn.com](http://www.hello.shawn.com)* it will redirect to *hello.shawn.com* I have managed htaccess to access this but its not working properly.

here is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shawn\.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.shawn.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: I used your mentioned link solution but unfortunely my server has been crushed. so now its not working and i move on previous on now nothing working on my server? @KamleshPaul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it would seem you just need to remove the `www` subdomain, on whatever hostname is requested. Obviously the `www` subdomain must currently resolve to the same place.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>    RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
>    RewriteEngine On 
>    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
>    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?shawn\.com
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.shawn.com/$1 [R,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

Your current directives are in the wrong order. I assume you must have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory (that does the actual routing through the Laravel front-controller)? In which case, the second rule (that redirects HTTP to HTTPS+www) is never processed - just as well really, since this would expose the `/public` subdirectory (presumably hidden from the URL) and would seem to be the opposite of what you are trying to achieve (ie. *removal* of www).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove "www" subdomain from any hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+?)\.?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite everything to the "/public" subdirectory
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required and should be removed.

No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

The `%1` backreference in the first rule contains the hostname, less the `www.` prefix, captured from the preceding *condition*.

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid a potential caching issue. You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Answer (score 0):

Salam. If do you need to access for subdomen **[www.hello.shawn.com](http://www.hello.shawn.com)** then you  must write this statement once again.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hello\.shawn\.com
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hello.shawn.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Salam, Its not mandotory to add subdomain its perfectly okay my problem is in `www` if anyone visit with `www` it will redirected to main domain thats it..