# How to redirect www to non-www next.js app in cpanel on apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, next.js, cpanel

I have deployed my next.js app to cpanel as a standalone build and everything works properly when requesting my domain without www like this: `example.com`
But when I request like `www.example.com` the GET request fails to complete.

Here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/username/public_html/App.Next"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/username/nodevenv/public_html/App.Next/18/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile /home/username/public_html/App.Next/server.js
PassengerAppLogFile "/home/username/logs/passenger.log"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How do I redirect `http://www.example.com` to `https://example.com` with `301` status code?

Apache Version:     **2.4.57**

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all requests to non-www, add the following lines at the beginning of your website’s .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So edited version of your .htaccess file:

```
# Force www to non-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/username/public_html/App.Next"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerNodejs "/home/username/nodevenv/public_html/App.Next/18/bin/node"
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile /home/username/public_html/App.Next/server.js
PassengerAppLogFile "/home/username/logs/passenger.log"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You can follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270281/16099117) for more detailed info at comments.