# Redirect www to non-www in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i have problem in Redirect urls when i try enter https://www.maindomain.com/sitemap_index.xml its not redirect to https://maindomain.com/sitemap_index.xml and this make problem in google console

i'am trying this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(sitemap_index\.xml)$  http://www.%{HTTPS_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic htaccess redirect www to non-www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www)

Comment: Your rule implements the opposite redirection of what you ask in the question. it redirects from the name without trailing "www." to the hostname with.

Comment: no i need redirection from www to non www sitpmap.xml